# Language translation using PHP

Tags: php, language-translation

Hi i am devloping sample site in php i need to translate whole website in to persian. how can it possible in php?? I have tried using the following code.. This code will working fine for deutsch conversion.

```
1. class.translation.php

<?php
class Translator {

    private $language   = 'en';
    private $lang       = array();

    public function __construct($language){
        $this->language = $language;
    }

    private function findString($str) {
        if (array_key_exists($str, $this->lang[$this->language])) {
            echo $this->lang[$this->language][$str];
            return;
        }
        echo $str;
    }

    private function splitStrings($str) {
        return explode('=',trim($str));
    }

    public function __($str) {  
        if (!array_key_exists($this->language, $this->lang)) {
            if (file_exists($this->language.'.txt')) {
                $strings = array_map(array($this,'splitStrings'),file($this->language.'.txt'));
                foreach ($strings as $k => $v) {
                    $this->lang[$this->language][$v[0]] = $v[1];
                }
                return $this->findString($str);
            }
            else {
                echo $str;
            }
        }
        else {
            return $this->findString($str);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

2.Register.php

```
<?php
require_once('class.translation.php');

if(isset($_GET['lang']))
    $translate = new Translator($_GET['lang']);
else
    $translate = new Translator('en');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title><?php $translate->__('CSS Registration Form'); ?></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>    
        <form action="" class="register">
            <h1><?php $translate->__('Registration'); ?><a class="flag_deutsch" title="deutsch" href="register1.php?lang=de"></a><a class="flag_english" title="english" href="register1.php"></a></h1>
            <fieldset class="row1">
                <legend><?php $translate->__('Account Details'); ?></legend>
                <p>
                    <label><?php $translate->__('Email'); ?> *</label>
                    <input type="text"/>
                    <label><?php $translate->__('Repeat email'); ?> *</label>
                    <input type="text"/>
                </p>
            </fieldset>

            <div><button class="button"><?php $translate->__('Register'); ?> &raquo;</button></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to transilate to other laguages using this code?? I changed register1.php?lang=de to register1.php?lang=fa(persian).. But nothing hapens..anybody plese help

Comment: Please note the class that you are using for translation.

Comment: You need a file called `fa.txt` with the translation strings inside.

Comment: I think the idea given by Harry is good for you.

Comment: I made this little translation library, may be you or someone else could use it.
https://github.com/amitkhare/easy-translator/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

AS per me you can try this method.This method is already implemented in our system and it is working properly.

Make php file of each language and define all the variables and use those variables in pages.

for e.g 
For english

**english.php**

```
$hello="Hello";
```

**persian.php**

```
$hello=html_entity_decode(htmlentities("سلام"));
```

Now use this variable to  page like this.

**your_page.php**

```
<label><?php echo $hello; ?></label>
```

You have load specific language file as per get language variable from URL.

It is better that you have define this language variable into config file.

**config.php**

```
if(isset($_GET['lang']) && $_GET['lang']=='persian')
{
   require_once('persian.php');
}
else
{
   require_once('english.php');
}
```

Comment: I guess you're wasting the server resources by defining variables. In fact they're not variables at all ...

Comment: @Harry What do you mean? You mean I should not suggest my idea, because it's mine and I should looking for any other alternatives that should be differ from my idea?! ... see my update on my answer to see why it's better defining `Constants` rather `Variables`.

Comment: @Mahdi I have commented before see your answer

Answer (score 10):

```
original from @rbenmass :
```

try this:

```
function translate($q, $sl, $tl){
    $res= file_get_contents("https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&dt=bd&dt=ex&dt=ld&dt=md&dt=qca&dt=rw&dt=rm&dt=ss&dt=t&dt=at&sl=".$sl."&tl=".$tl."&hl=hl&q=".urlencode($q), $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/transes.html");
    $res=json_decode($res);
    return $res[0][0][0];
}

//example-- 
echo translate("اسمي منتصر الصاوي", "ar", "en");
```

Comment: it worked man. great thanks

Comment: what is the limit of this url ?

Answer (score 9):

If I were you, I'd do it like this:

**/inc/lang/en.lang.php**

```
define('_HELLO', 'Hello');
```

**/inc/lang/fa.lang.php**

```
define('_HELLO', 'سلام');
```

**index.php**

```
// $_SESSION['lang'] could be 'en', 'fa', etc.
require_once '/inc/lang/' . $_SESSION['lang'] . 'lang.php';

echo _HELLO;
```

**Benchmark: Constants vs. Variables**

Here you see why I offered using `Constants` not `Variables`:

**const.php**

```
echo memory_get_usage() . '<br>';   // output: 674,576

for ($i = 0; $i <= 10000; $i++) {
    define($i, 'abc');
}

echo memory_get_usage() . '<br>';   // output: 994,784
```

**var.php**

```
echo memory_get_usage() . '<br>';   // output: 674,184

for ($i = 0; $i <= 10000; $i++) {
   $$i = 'abc';
}

echo memory_get_usage() . '<br>';   // output: 2,485,176
```

Comment: If you use define then it does not use server resource ?

Comment: @Harry please read my comment on your answer again. I said `I guess you're wasting the server resources by defining variables.` ... see my update on my answer ... hope it helps you.

Answer (score 5):

**From an Perl trans script I extracted the following for 100% free  php google translation this function:**

See working demo on http://ogena.net

```
function translate($q, $sl, $tl){

if($s==$e || $s=='' || $e==''){
    return $q;

}
else{
    $res="";

    $qqq=explode(".", $q);

    if(count($qqq)<2){

        @unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/transes.html");
        copy("http://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&dt=bd&dt=ex&dt=ld&dt=md&dt=qca&dt=rw&dt=rm&dt=ss&dt=t&dt=at&sl=".$sl."&tl=".$tl."&hl=hl&q=".urlencode($q), $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/transes.html");
        if(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/transes.html")){
            $dara=file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/transes.html");
            $f=explode("\"", $dara);

            $res.= $f[1];
        }
    }
    else{


    for($i=0;$i<(count($qqq)-1);$i++){

        if($qqq[$i]==' ' || $qqq[$i]==''){
        }
        else{
            copy("http://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&dt=bd&dt=ex&dt=ld&dt=md&dt=qca&dt=rw&dt=rm&dt=ss&dt=t&dt=at&sl=".$s."&tl=".$e."&hl=hl&q=".urlencode($qqq[$i]), $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/transes.html");

            $dara=file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/transes.html");
            @unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/transes.html");
            $f=explode("\"", $dara);

            $res.= $f[1].". ";
            }
        }
    }
    return $res;
}

}




//sample usage
echo translate("Goede dag dames en heren", "nl", "en");
```

Answer (score 4):

As i can read from the code, the translator class loads the translation data from en.txt file, if you want have 'fa' translation, just create fa.txt as copy of en.txt with all translations and edit and translate fa.txt to persian...

Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

@rbenmass
Thank You :-)

I think it have to be , because it runs good for me :

```
    /* 
    original from @rbenmass :

    function translate($q, $sl, $tl){

    if($s==$e || $s=='' || $e==''){
        return $q;

    }
     **/

function translate($q, $sl, $tl){

if($sl==$tl || $sl=='' || $tl==''){
    return $q;

}
//  ...  //
```