# GET/POST convert to UTF-8 in php

Tags: php, post, utf-8, character-encoding, get

I'm reading a lot about UTF-8 and encoding but I'm lost,

I simply want to parse a string with a `GET`/`POST` in php and if it contains something else that UTF-8 to convert it (in my occasion Greek)

so my faulty code is:

```
$title = $_GET['title'];
//and sometimes I use this:
$info = htmlspecialchars(trim($_GET['info']));

echo $title, $info;
```

and it echoes `Î»ÎµÎ¾Î· Î»Î­Î¾Î·1` for some greek characters given (which is wrong of course).

Thanks

**Update:**
Just wanted to update with my solution in case somebody reads this. The problem was just one line which was missing:

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $con);
```

With `$con` of course handling the `mysql_connect`

Comment: See this may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13172660/language-translation-using-php/13173435#13173435

Comment: Other link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208149/php-with-special-characters-like-n/13208272#13208272

Comment: @Harry isn't something more simple like that: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php#105335 (which I cannot understand how to use) Or add a `ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8"` on my `$_GET` ?

Comment: @DDL499 Use html_entity_decode() function I think your problem is solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *know* what encoding a string is in. Converting anything and everything from an unknown encoding to UTF-8 is simply not possible. You need to convey through meta information how a certain string is encoded and handle it appropriately. How this is done exactly depends on what exactly you want to do. Preferably you do no encoding conversion at all at any point, but keep everything in UTF-8 front to back.

I'd recommend you look into:

- [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)
- [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: thanks for writing this. Really. I feel way more comfortable with encoding stuff

Comment: Glad to hear it. Good to know it helped. :)